# Discrepancies in select value(disabled option) in jQuery old and newer version

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have updated jquery version from 1.7.2 to 2.1.1 in my project and used jquery migrate for fallback.

I found an issue related to value of select in jQuery 2.1.1 and 1.7.2.

1.7.2 --> "" (Blank)

2.1.1 --> null

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/ritesh14887/pen/VmWGeo)

```
console.log("Version>>> 1.7.2 >>>> " + $jq("select").val());
console.log("Version>>> 2.1.1  >>> " + $("select").val());
```

Has anyone come around the similar issue and its workaround?

P.S : I am using Native JS for the time being to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

With the `:selected` jquery selector get what you expected?

`$("select option:selected")`

Comment: Thanks for response! There are so many alternatives to do this, but question here is why jquery returning different results in different versions.